# SUM in dataframe of rows that has the same date and ADD new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sum

My code starts this way: it takes data from [HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/italia/covid19-opendata-%20%20%20%20%20%20vaccini/master/dati/somministrazioni-vaccini-latest.csv) and I want to extract al the rows that contain "fascia_anagrafica" equal to "20-29". In italian "fascia_anagrafica" means "age range". That was relatively simple, as you see below, and I dropped some unimportant values.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy
import sympy
from numpy import arange,exp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot
import math
import decimal

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/italia/covid19-opendata- 
vaccini/master/dati/somministrazioni-vaccini-latest.csv') 

df = df[df["fascia_anagrafica"] == "20-29"]

df01=df.drop(columns= ["fornitore","area","sesso_maschile","sesso_femminile","seconda_dose","pregressa_infezione","dose_aggiuntiva","codice_NUTS1","codice_NUTS2","codice_regione_ISTAT","nome_area"])
```

now dataframe looks like this:[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6bVd.png)

as you see, for every date there is the "20-29 age range" and for every line you may find the value "prima_dose" which stands for "first_dose".

Now the problem:
If you take into consideration the date "2020-12-27" you will notice that it is repeated about 20 times (with 20 different values) since in italy there are 21 regions, then the same applies for the other dates. **Unfortunately they are not always 21, because in certain regions they didn't put any values in some days so the dataframe is NOT periodic.**

I want to add a column in the dataframe that makes a sum of the values that has same date fo all dates in the dataframe. An exaple here:

Date.................prima_dose...........sum_column

2020-8-9.............. 1.......................13     <----this is  (1+3+4+5 in the day 2020-8-9)

2020-8-9..............3........................8      <----this is  (2+5+1  in the day 2020-8-10)

2020-8-9..............                   4..............and so on...

2020-8-9..............                   5

2020-8-10..............                  2

2020-8-10..............                  5

2020-8-10..............                  1

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you just want to sum all the values of 'prima_dose' for each date and get the result in a new dataframe, you could use [`groupby.sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
result = df01.groupby('data_somministrazione')['prima_dose'].sum().reset_index()
```

Prints:

```
>>>  result

    data_somministrazione  prima_dose
0              2020-12-27         700
1              2020-12-28         171
2              2020-12-29          87
3              2020-12-30         486
4              2020-12-31        2425
..                    ...         ...
289            2021-10-12       11583
290            2021-10-13       12532
291            2021-10-14       15347
292            2021-10-15       13689
293            2021-10-16        9293

[294 rows x 2 columns]
```

This will change the structure of your current dataframe, and return a unique row per date

---

If you want to add a new column in your existing dataframe without altering it's structure, you should use [`groupby.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df01['prima_dose_per_date'] = df01.groupby('data_somministrazione')['prima_dose'].transform('sum')
```

Prints:

```
>>> df01

       data_somministrazione fascia_anagrafica  prima_dose  prima_dose_per_date
0                 2020-12-27             20-29           2                  700
7                 2020-12-27             20-29           9                  700
12                2020-12-27             20-29          60                  700
17                2020-12-27             20-29          59                  700
23                2020-12-27             20-29         139                  700
                     ...               ...         ...                  ...
138475            2021-10-16             20-29         533                 9293
138484            2021-10-16             20-29         112                 9293
138493            2021-10-16             20-29           0                 9293
138502            2021-10-16             20-29         529                 9293
138515            2021-10-16             20-29           0                 9293

[15595 rows x 4 columns]
```

This will keep the current structure of your dataframe and return a new column with the sum of prima_dose per each date.